# How to add along an axis in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I would like to add to a tensor a matrix.

This works

```
numpy.zeros((4,4,4))+numpy.sum(numpy.ones((4,4,4)),axis=2)
```

This doesn't work.

```
numpy.zeros((3,4,5))+numpy.sum(numpy.ones((3,4,5)),axis=2)
ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (3,4,5) (3,4)
```

How to get the second example working? I want to add along the third axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Broadcast](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html)

```
numpy.zeros((3,4,5))+numpy.sum(numpy.ones((3,4,5)),axis=2)[...,None]
```

Comment: if I wanted to add along axis=1, what would it be?

Comment: `numpy.zeros((3,4,5))+numpy.sum(numpy.ones((3,4,5)),axis=1)[:,None,:]` . Equivalent to my original answer is `numpy.zeros((3,4,5))+numpy.sum(numpy.ones((3,4,5)),axis=2)[:,:,,None]`

Comment: Though more verbose, it's probably more clear to write `np.newaxis` instead of `None` to add an axis (`np.newaxis is None == True`).